# Error using session storage with Angular 10

Tags: angular, spring, authentication

I'm developing a website for my university in Angular 10, and I have a TokenStorageService that checks if the user is loggedIn and returns a token and the user's roles. I'm calling my service in my constructor and setting the user on my ngOnInit but I'm getting null. Can anybody help me with that?

- TokenStorageService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {

    constructor() { }

    signOut() {
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }

    logout() {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    }

    public saveToken(token: string) {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
    }

    public getToken(): string {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    }

    public saveUser(user) {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
    }

    public getUser() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)));
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY));
    }
}
```

- My component where I call it

```
export class AutorizarCriacaoContaComponent implements OnInit {
    
    currentUser: any;
    tipoUsuario: number;
    authToken: string;
    tipo: string;
    // usuario solicitante
    u = {} as Usuario;

    constructor(private token: TokenStorageService, private router: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private accountService: AccountService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
        this.authToken = this.actRoute.snapshot.params.authToken;
        // this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // console.log(this.token.getToken());
        this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
        this.getRoles();
        this.getUsuarioBytoken();
    }

    getRoles() {
        for (let role of this.currentUser.roles) {
            // tslint:disable: triple-equals
            // console.log(this.currentUser.roles.includes('ROLE_ALUNO'));
            if (role.authority == 'ROLE_ALUNO') {
                this.tipoUsuario = 1;
            }

            if (role.authority == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
                this.tipoUsuario = 2;
            }

            if (role.authority === 'ROLE_USER' || role.authority === 'ROLE_PROFESSOR') {
                this.tipoUsuario = 3;
            }
        }
        return this.tipoUsuario;
    }

    getUsuarioBytoken() {
        // tslint:disable: deprecation
        this.accountService.getUsuarioByToken(this.authToken).subscribe((v: VerificationToken) => {
            this.u = v.usuario;
            if (this.u.roles[0].type === 'ROLE_ALUNO') {
                this.tipo = 'aluno';
            }
            if (this.u.roles[0].type === 'ROLE_USER' || this.u.roles[0].type === 'ROLE_PROFESSOR') {
                this.tipo = 'professor';
            }
        });
    }

    autorizarConta() {
        this.spinner.show();
        // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
        this.accountService.autorizarConta(this.authToken).subscribe(response => {
            const res = response;
            if (res.result === 'conta.autorizada') {
                this.spinner.hide();
                Swal.fire(
                    'Tudo certo!',
                    'Conta autorizada!',
                    'success'
                );
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home2']);
                }, 4000);

            }
        });
    }

    redirect() {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { redirectUrl: '/conta/autorizar/' + this.authToken } });
    }
}
```

- The response I'm getting
  [Token as null on my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvVOL.png)

Comment: Are you able to see the value stored against 'auth-user' in browser session storage through develop tool? 

If not you are probably missing a step to saveUser() details based on your authentication.

Comment: Your component is calling the token service asking for the user, and the service printing `null` means it couldn't find the user in the `sessionStorage`. So, the question is who stored it in the first place. Check when you are calling the `saveUser()` method in the service, and make sure it gets stored.

Comment: It´s weird because I've already logged in before on another tab, before I access the url that throws that error    `this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if token service is initialised before reading from it.
check if following code works

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentUser = this.getCurrentUser();
  this.getRoles();
  this.getUsuarioBytoken();
}

getCurrentUser(): any {
    if (this.token.getUser()) {
        return this.token.getUser();
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => getCurrentUser(), 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: The service is already printing `null` on console.

Comment: Hi, it worked!!!! Thank you so much. I'm not really sure why it wasn't working on this specific component because I did something similar on anothers...

Comment: Happy to help @LarissaMenezes